# Data for Histogram in Python

Tags: python

I want to create data for plotting histogram in python. The data should be in bins and value format.
For example, input data:

```
a = [10,30,12.5,70,76,90,96,55,44.5,67.8,76,88]
```

I want output in table format like,
bins data

```
10  1   
20  1  
30  1  
40  0  
50  1  
60  1  
70  2  
80  2  
90  2      
100 1
```

How can i do this in python?

Comment: If you use `numpy`, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use any external modules and code it yourself, use something similar to this:

```
import math # You need this to perform extra math function, it is already built in

def histogram(lst): # Defining a function
    rounded_list = [(int(math.ceil(i / 10.0)) * 10) for i in lst] 
    # Rounding every value to the nearest ten

    d = {} # New dictionary

    for v in xrange(min(rounded_list),max(rounded_list)+10,10):
        d[v] = 0
    # Creating a dictionary with every ten value from minimum to maximum

    for v in rounded_list:
            d[v] += 1
    # Counting all the values

    for i in sorted(list(d.keys())):
        print ("\t".join([str(i),str(d[i])]))
    # Printing the output

a = [10,30,12.5,70,76,90,96,55,44.5,67.8,76,88]

#Calling the function
histogram(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the class `Counter` in `Collections` may help you.
And you can reference the [pygal](http://pygal.org/chart_types/) a dynamic SVG charting library.